# When should I add proofed yeast to a bread machine?

Tags: bread, yeast

I like to use proofed yeast when making bread. I want to use a bread machine but all
the recipes call for adding dry yeast to the dry ingredients before adding the liquid.  Since proofed yeast is basically a solution of water and dry yeast, when and where should it be added to the ingredients?

Comment: IMO- it sounds like you want to incorporate [artisanship](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/artisanship) with modern day technology. _Your the future_ innovate... Trial and error my friend.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The whole point of a bread machine is to have a "push a button and forget it" device which delivers less-than-stellar bread at a fraction of the effort. Proofing the yeast first will add effort, but it won't make your bread taste better. If you have doubts that your yeast will work and want to watch it go up first, there is no need for that: it was an issue in the early home-use dry yeasts in the 90s, but by now, the technology is mature enough. I've never had yeast fail in the last decades.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on why your bread machine is having you keep your yeast dry:

- If it's because you're putting a bunch of ingredients in the night before and setting the machine to have bread ready for breakfast (e.g., on a delay), then you have to use dry yeast. The yeast needs to stay dry so it doesn't start growing until the machine is ready to start.
- If its because the machine does a preheat cycle to warm up the flour/water/etc. before mixing, then add in the proofed yeast when mixing is about to start. That also means you'll probably want to wait until shortly before that to proof your yeast.
- If its just to make mixing easier, then combine it with the wet ingredients instead.

Remember to count the water/sugar/etc. from proofing the yeast as part of the total in the dough (e.g., if you proof in 100g of water, add 100g less water than the recipe calls for).

Answer (score 1):

Add all dry ingredients as ordinary, when it's time to start adding liquid ingredients, add the yeast starter and make sure to subtract an equal amount of water from the recipe.

It's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

As above poster says, but I add liquids in first, which includes yeast starter. I never get a good a rise if I just added yeast to flour , I really need a good activation in a jug of water.